# Send in http request body param as array - Invalid array

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I use extension **Advanced Rest client**
And I want to send POST request with 3 params in body.
On of them must be array.
I use this

[image]

but I get error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid array",
"param": "payment_method_types",
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you entered is not valid application/www-url-encoded value. In the editor you have "Encode payload" button that transforms the value you entered to valid message. It should be something like:

```
success_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsuccess&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcancel&payment_method_types=%5B%22card%22%5D
```

You can see the exact sent message in the response details, under request headers, and the "source message".